# Как посчитать количество элементов ul в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Хочу сделать меню в две строки, для этого мне нужно посчитать количество элементов ul, какая функция в javascript отвечает за это?
Пробовал примерно так:

```
<ul>
    <li>Главная</li>
    <li>Контакты</li>
    <li>Резюме</li>
    <li>Портфолио</li>
    <li>Услуги</li>
    <li>Стихи</li>
    <li>Программы</li>
    <li>Статьи</li>
</ul>

<script>
    var spis = document.ul.li.length;
    document.write('Кол-во элементов ul '+spis);
</script>
```

Скрипт должен считать количество li и после каждой 4-ой, переводить остальные на следующую строку.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы! Я так понимаю javascript пофигу, где стоять: до элементов ul или после них?

Comment: Нет, конечно. Либо после, либо нужно вызывать код по событию onload (или его более продвинутым вариантам).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Как минимум есть два способа

```
<ul id="mymenu">
    <li>aaaa</li>
    <li>bbbb</li>
    ......
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // способ 1:
    alert(document.getElementById('mymenu').childNodes.length);

    // способ 2:
    alert(document.getElementById('mymenu').getElementsByTagName('li').length);
</script>
```

Comment: Первый способ посчитает ещё и все текстовые узлы.

Answer (score 4):

```
<script>
    var spis = document.ul.li.length;
    document.write('Кол-во элементов ul '+spis);
</script>
```

Этот код не валидный DOM, нужно использовать dom-функции:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].getElementsByTagName('li');
```

Но именно Ваша задача решается так:

```
<style>
    ul li {
        float: left;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
    }
</style>
<ul>
    <li>element 1</li>
    <li>element 2</li>
    <li>element 3</li>
    <li>element 4</li>
    <li>element 5</li>
    <li>element 6</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

или так:

```
var len = document.querySelector('ul').children.length;
```